# Text in Scrollview won't match parent height

Tags: android, scrollview, nine-patch

For some reason, my scrollview, which only contains two TextViews for now, refuses to fill it's parent.  The XML for the scrollview is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Article"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp" 
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've noticed the text in the scrollview will not cover parts of the .9.png `@drawable/background`.  I've tested several backgrounds, and wherever I put a patch, the text will only go in the stretched part.  I uploaded a picture here.

[image: scrollview error]

In this case, the horizontal patch is nearly on the bottom of the 150x150 image.  It's one pixel off.  As you can see, the textview cuts off sometime well before the top, and there is a 1 pixel cutoff on the bottom.

If I were to make the patch in the middle of the .png, the cutoff would be split evenly top and bottom.  It is doing the same thing horizontally, but that is much more difficult to see since the text does not scroll horizontally.

How do I get rid of this behavior?  I want the text to be able to flow from the very top to the very bottom, over the .9.png.  Is this possible?  If not, the only option I see here is make it a very short narrow 9patch so it doesn't take up much space.  I'd like a better solution though.

Edit: the background image (the 9patch, not sure if the patches will come through though)

[image: 9patch background]

If they don't, it's got a 1 pixel wide horizontal patch at the bottom, and a a pixel wide vertical patch at the top.  See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the image you use as the background?

Comment: Hmm it's working as expected on N1 Android 2.3.6without any spacing described her. Does it occur on every device you tested, and do you chafe the layout programmically?

Comment: Yep, I get the gap seen on phones, tablets, and emulators running 3.0+.  Haven't tried it with anything lower, since the app I'm working on isn't compatible.  I'll probabaly go with a smaller 9patch.  Thanks for trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a smaller .9.png.  It seems that the textview is only filling the expanded portion of the 9patch.  At least on ICS.